# How to add a default date in streamlit date_input

Tags: datetime, streamlit

I have a date input and want to make yesterday as the default date.

```py
import datetime
import streamlit as st

complition_date = st.date_input("Date of completion", datetime.date(2017, 08, 19))
```

How can I acomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import datetime
import streamlit as st
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()

default_date_yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)

complition_date = st.date_input("Date of completion", default_date_yesterday)
```